# jquery ui accordion draggable and resizable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery ui in my web app for an accordion menu box.  I am able to add items to the accordion well enough. And it is .draggable.  However, I would like it to also be .resizable if possible however I can't figure out how to get this to work.  Here is my relevant html portion:

```
<div id="layer_accordion">
        <h3><a href="#Accordion1"></a></h3>
        <div>
        </div>
</div>
```

And here is the jquery portion:

```
$("#layer_accordion").draggable({ cursorAt: { top: -10, left: -10 } });
// now initiate accordion
$("#layer_accordion").accordion({ clearStyle: true, autoHeight: false });
$('#layer_accordion').accordion('activate', 1);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers, 
Derek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting any JS errors in your console? Are there any styles that may be getting in the way of letting this operate correctly?

I was able to get this to work. Using JQuery 1.7.2 & JQuery UI 1.8.23 You'll have to look at the CSS on the JQuery UI docs to see how they keep the resizing handle on the bottom right.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/

It's ugly but here is all the code I have :

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #layer_accordion { border: 1px solid #000; width: 200px; display:inline-block;}
        .ui-resizable-handle { width: 16px; border: 1px solid #0f0; height: 16px;}
    </style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="layer_accordion">
        <h3><a href="#Accordion1">asdf</a></h3>
        <div>
            content 1
        </div>
        <h3><a href="#Accordion2">asdf</a></h3>
        <div>
            content 2
        </div>
</div>
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#layer_accordion").draggable({ cursorAt: { top: -10, left: -10 } });
        $("#layer_accordion").accordion({ clearStyle: true, autoHeight: false });
        $('#layer_accordion').accordion('activate', 1);
        $('#layer_accordion').resizable();
    });

    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello Brian, Thanks for you feedback.  Your snippit made me realize that I was missing a library reference to jquery.ui.resizable.js.  It works now.